# Complex number inequality $\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\Im(z^k)\right| < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\Re\left(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z^{2k}}{|z|^{2k}}\right)}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> If $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ with $|z|< \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $n$ is a
>   positive integer, prove that:
>
> $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\Im(z^k)\right| < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\Re\left(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z^{2k}}{|z|^{2k}}\right)}$$

I coould not prove this inequality. It is from an old preparation test at my school (2001). I tried with polar form $z=|z|(\cos a+i\sin a)$ and I arrive at:

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|z|^k\sin(ka)\right)^2 < \frac{1}{2}\left(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(2ka)\right)$$

but no further success.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your statement. It should be $z^{2k}$ in the numerator of summand, since you seem to arrive at something equivalent with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof**: We have
\begin{align}
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n |z|^k \sin k a\Big)^2
&\le \Big(\sum_{k=1}^n |z|^k |\sin k a|\Big)^2\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n |z|^{2k} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin ka|^2 \tag{1}\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \sin^2 ka\tag{2}\\
&< \sum_{k=1}^n \sin^2 ka \tag{3}.
\end{align}
Explanation: in (1), we have used Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality;
in (2), we have used $|z| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$; in (3), we have used $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} 
= 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} < 1$.

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\Big(n - \sum_{k=1}^n \cos 2k a\Big)
&= \frac{1}{2}\Big(n - \sum_{k=1}^n (1 - 2\sin^2 ka)\Big)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sin^2 ka.
\end{align}

We are done.

Comment: +1 I tried this, but I failed to see the geometric progression.